# How to print a string followed by the result of a function in Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have a function `trip_cost` which calculates the total cost of a vacation. If I want to print the result of the function I can do so without problem like so:

```
print trip_cost(city, days, spending_money)
```

However if I try to code a more presentable, user-friendly version using a string I get a `Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax`

```
print "Your total trip cost is: " trip_cost(city, days, spending_money)
```

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) string method:

```
print "Your total trip cost is: {}".format(trip_cost(city, days, spending_money))
```

Update for Python 3.6+:

You can use [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) in Python 3.6+

```
print(f"Your total trip cost is: {trip_cost(city, days, spending_money)}")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.format()`:

```
print "Your total trip cost is: {}".format(trip_cost(city, days, spending_money))
```

See [String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting)

> `format(format_string, *args, **kwargs)` format() is the primary API
>   method. It takes a format string and an arbitrary set of positional
>   and keyword arguments. format() is just a wrapper that calls
>   vformat().

Answer (score 2):

Use str

```
print "Your total trip cost is: " + str(trip_cost(city, days, spending_money))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use **format**

Or %s specifier

```
print "Your total trip cost is: {}".format(trip_cost(city, days, spending_money))
```

OR

```
print "Your total trip cost is: %s"%(trip_cost(city, days, spending_money))
```