# How to add variables into a string?

Tags: python, string

I have an empty string **strLocation** and I would like to insert the three variables x, y and z to make the string a location of a point which is **(x,y,z)**. I know I cannot simply add 'x' 'y' and 'z' because that will just add the letters instead of the actual values they hold. What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a string followed by the result of a function in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076273/how-to-print-a-string-followed-by-the-result-of-a-function-in-python)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str_location = '({0}, {1}, {2})'.format(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
 strLocation = "("+str(x)+","+str(y)+","+str(z)+")"
```

?

Comment: @Kroltan It doesn't, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121115/python-implicit-conversion-of-object-to-str/32121506#32121506) for someone having that problem.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Thanks for the reference. Been using Javascript for too long :)